# PHP -v shows 7.2.8 version on Mac where as it has php 7.4.8

Tags: php, linux

How to configure PHP 7.4.X in to mac where as it shows 7.2.8 on Php -v command. I tried to install latest version of XXAMP which come with 7.4.8 but still the problem remains the same.

Comment: PHP 7.2.8 is a CLI version and you have PHP 7.4.x in XXAMP which runs with Apache webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use brew to achieve this:

```
$ brew unlink php@7.2
$ brew install php@7.4
$ brew link php@7.4 --force
```

Then in the future you can reverse this by doing this:

```
$ brew unlink php@7.4
$ brew link php@7.2 --force
```